# Downloading an external package in anaconda

Tags: python, installation, package

I went to command line and typed

```
conda install pywt
```

It showed me

> PackageNotFoundError: Package could not found: Conda could not find '

However I have the data package downloaded on my PC. Please tell me what is there that I am missing?

Comment: What is `pywt`? Is it `pywavelets`? If yes, try this: `conda install -c conda-forge pywavelets=0.5.2`

Comment: Done!! Thank you a lot ^_^